# What is the easiest way to put on a bracelet ('S-hook') pin with one hand without anyone help?

Tags: substitute-tool

It is always very difficult for me to put on bracelet hooks with one hand when trying to head out the door. I wear the bracelet on my right hand, which is my dominant hand as I wear a watch on my left, so I have to use my non-dominant hand to put it on. I usually sit and place my right hand on my thigh for support and slowly put it on. It usually takes at least 2-3 minutes.

Are there any faster ways to put it on? My bracelet is similar to the one shown below.

[image]

Comment: @Zach, why do you think that [hands] don't fit this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Using sellotape

You can stick the base end of the bracelet to your wrist with a sellotape, so that it will not move and helps you to link the other end faster.

[image: sellotape]

2. Use paper clip

You can also use anything to hold it from moving. Use paper clip to hang the other end and now you can easily link the other.

[image: paper clip]

Answer (score 2):

I use a rubber band. I'll break down the process, step by step:

1. Slip rubber band over wrist.
2. Lay bracelet across wrist.
3. Take a bit of the rubber band and put it over part of the bracelet -- now the bracelet will stay put while you angle yourself to hook it.

If you accidentally lose track of where the rubber band is in relationship to the bracelet and the bracelet is now going through the band, just cut off the rubber band and start over with another one.

Comment: Please consider [registering](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.